# How can I select a suitable cable with these characteristics: 690 V, 550 A, 1 km long, AC three phase underwater cable

Tags: power, cables, low-voltage, underwater

How can I select a suitable cable with this characteristics:

- The cable is connected at one end to a 690 V power generator that is between 6 and 40 meter below the surface of a big river and converts the kinetic energy of the water into electricity, directedly, without a dam.
- A step up transformer from 690 V to a higher voltage, for diminishing the losses, mounted underwater is not accepted for technical and safety reasons.
- The max current through the cable is 550 A.
- The cable should be able to carry a three phase AC current having a frequency of between 20 and 30 Hz.
- The length of the cable is between 800 and 1200 meters and it ends on the bank of the river.
- Accepted power losses in the cable are max 40 kW.
- Preferably, the cable should carry also an optical fibre for communicating with the controller of the underwater generator.

I have found on the internet high voltage underwater cables but it appears that, not knowing where to look for with precision, the type of cable with the characteristics I enumerated above is difficult to find. Can you help me with some advices for finding such a less usual cable?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem or someone in over their head in project that should be outsourced.  An experienced person should be doing the water-tight slices let alone specifying and sourcing the cable.

Comment: If 40kW losses are acceptable, the overall power must be quite high snd the river flowing quite fast.  Fast flowing water will create an erosive environment so you can't just specify waterproof cable (specified for still water), you'll need to consider the rocks, gravel, sand and silt flowing past the cable which can be like sandpaper constantly eroding it.

Comment: After a week or so of searching the net I was not able to find the cable with the characteristics I mentioned. Please do not discourage people to give an useful answer. This is neither a homework nor an outsourcing project. I need this cable.

Comment: The cable can be buried in the river bed if the generator proves successful. The power of the generator is 500 to 700 kW.

Comment: Tests will be done with the cable introduced in a 6 meter deep canal where the water does not flow. A 690 V, 600 kW generator on the ground will pump current through this underwater cable that will be connected to a load, also on the ground, 1 km away from the generator.

Comment: This is a very difficult application, both due to the harsh physical environment, the length, the high current and the low frequency. Your cable will be extremely expensive - so expensive, in fact, that contracting a certified electrician will have a comparable or lower cost to the parts. I have very low confidence that this problem will meet regulatory and safety standards without participation from a licensed professional.

Comment: If the cable is buried in the river bed, it may overheat if thermal conductivity of the bed material is too low.

Comment: Do you know the statistics over several years of the temperature of the river bed?

Comment: @Reinderien , I expect costs of the cable between $10000 and $20000. Yes, contacting a specialized technician would be a good idea but where can I find a man having experience with cables the type I need? For example, seeing on the site https://nassaunationalcable.com/products/500-03-heavy-duty-flat-grnd-thw-copper-600v a power cable,  for submersible water pumps, rated 600 V, 380 A, I contacted the sales guy and told him what I needed and he said he would try to find a solution after talking with some technical people but I am still waiting for his answer.

Comment: @Antonio51, The cable will be first tested, with a generator, in Canada in a river north of the parallel 46. I do not know with precision the river bed temperature or thermal conductivity.

Comment: I would also not rule out suspension above the river rather than burial/immersion, and also high-voltage transformation at the beginning to increase efficiency and reduce weight.

Comment: @Reinderien , Here is the big issue, that a step up transformer from 690 V to an upper voltage, which can only be underwater, placed near the generator, is not allowed (I have already written this detail).

Comment: Ok, but you should perhaps get these pieces of information at one "meteorological center" or some "satellite temperature" measurements? For thermal conductivity, use perhaps the "lower" value in 'steady" currents for first sizing. And for the river bed temperature, do some measurements when it is the mean "highest" over 1 day.

Comment: Something as this:  https://seatemperature.info/fr/golfe-du-saint-laurent-temperature-de-leau-de-la-mer.html#:~:text=Tout%20au%20long%20de%20l,est%20de%209%C2%B0C.

Comment: Unfortunately, the cable 500/3 HEAVY DUTY FLAT W/GRND THW/SUBMERSIBLE PUMP CABLE COPPER 600V costs $78.59/ft and this amounts to $257,775/km, so it appears that the cable I need (which has higher requirements than this one I found) is much more expensive than I had expected. Anyway, it is still of interest, as long as, tests with an 100 m cable, costing $25,777 are acceptable for the beginning.

Comment: One piece of information perhaps useful ... for your tests, I remember (but not sure, it was a long time ago ...) that one optical fiber (inserted in some THT cable ?) could be used also for "measuring" temperature along the cable (don't know "how"). https://storage.googleapis.com/fluves-website/documents/FR-CE-brochure_WEB_FLUVES2021.pdf

Comment: And this, sorry in french https://www.solexperts.com/fr/gtc/gtcmessverfahren-fr/gtcmessverfahren-faseroptik-fr#:~:text=Le%20principe%20de%20mesure%20de,Raman%20sur%20la%20lumi%C3%A8re%20r%C3%A9trodiffus%C3%A9e.  For cable lengths of up to 10 km, a temperature measurement accuracy of better than 0.1°C and a spatial resolution of approximately 0.7 m can be achieved.

Comment: @Antonio51 , No problem, I can read texts in French. That article about how one can measure the temperature along a cable containing an optical fibre is really interesting because from the bank of the river you can have a real time map of the temp along the cable and, if it increases above an accepted limit, the load can be disconnected to avoid overheating.

Comment: Don't know if this can help https://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html?necmaterial=copper&necwiresize=8&necconduit=pvc&necpf=0.85&material=copper&wiresize=0.2028&resistance=1.2&resistanceunit=okm&voltage=690&phase=ac3&noofconductor=9&distance=100&distanceunit=meters&amperes=550&x=43&y=15&ctype=nec

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135762/discussion-between-robert-werner-and-antonio51).

Answer (score 3):

For something as out there as this you absolutely need to be talking to the applications engineers at the cable manufacturers, likely one of the specialist sub surface ones.

There should however be extensive experience in the offshore wind power industry, so I would be talking to someone like the Prysmian group or Tratos who do sub sea power (This is on the small side for them). In particular I think Tratos might be able to do you a variant on their tidal stream turbine cable that may be suitable, but all of this is very much a case of talk to a vendors applications engineering folk.

I would expect this to be a very expensive cable.

Comment: After reading your answer I sent an email to Tratos describing in detail the cable I need. If they answer I will write here what they say.